# How can I cast a DateTime string format to other DateTime?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a string that is: `Thu, 16 May 2019 08:45:15 GMT` and I need to cast it to two strings: `16/05/2019` and `08:45:15`.

I have tryed many ways (I have seen other post of StackOverFlow) but I did not achieve that.

How could I do that?

EDIT 1:

I have tryed, for example, this code:

```
console.log(
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
    'en-US', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit' }
  ).format("Thu, 16 May 2019 08:45:15 GMT"))
```

The problem is all examples I see are from `Date.now()` (typeof Datetime) not a custom string like mine

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: Ok, I hace updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to convert that string

note: Since you are using GMT time, you'll want to call the `.getUTC*` function names

Also note that months are zero-indexed, so you'll need to add one to that.

```js
var d = new Date("Thu, 16 May 2019 08:45:15 GMT");
var dateStr = d.getUTCDate() + '/' + (d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getUTCFullYear();
var timeStr = d.getUTCHours() + ':' + d.getUTCMinutes() + ':' + d.getUTCSeconds();

console.log(dateStr);
console.log(timeStr);
```

or given your example using `Intl.DateTimeFormat` you can just add a `new Date()` object in there (instead of a plain string) and you're good to go.

```js
var d = new Date("Thu, 16 May 2019 08:45:15 GMT");

var formatted = Intl.DateTimeFormat(
  'en-US', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit'
  }).format(d);
  
console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: Just saw your updated question with the `Intl` example, please see my updated answer as well.

Comment: I have saw that, that is cool, thank you so much, again. I will go to use it inmediatly :)